shrinkwrap modifier - snap mode : project. Need to make a shoe box that has the interior shaped like the shoe to fit in?
I added shrinkwrap to a plane which would then project on to the bottom of the shoe, added another plane just before the top end of the shoe. Auxiliary targeted the plane2. Doing this should create a hollow space that is the shape of the shoe for the shoe to fit in (when the shoe is hid)/ from Derek Eliots video shoe reveal. But it didnt just appears as a normal plane. What am i doing wrong
